# Avoiding twice coding, One in if Condition and One in Assignment - C#

Tags: c#

Here is my sample code:

```
if (_Timing != target.Split(':')[0] + ": ")
   _Timing = target.Split(':')[0] + ": ";
```

I check if `_Timing` is not equal to `target.Split(':')[0] + ": "` then I will assing it to `_Timing`. I execute this `target.Split(':')[0] + ": "` two times. I need to avoid it.

another example is this:

```
if (db.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Joe") != null)
   var a = db.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Joe");
```

here again, I execute `db.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Joe")` two times. These samples are just some examples. I need to avoid twice coding like these.

I can do this due to answers received:

```
var splitted= target.Split(':')[0] + ": ";
if (_Timing != splitted)
   _Timing = splitted;
```

But I don't want to do something like this, because `splitted` will remain in memory. I'm looking for a way to not saving this temporary data into memory.

Is there any advice?

Comment: That variable is always there, even if you don't give it a name.  The processor needs it to implement the if() expression test.  So no point whatsoever in fretting over "remain in memory".  It doesn't btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hold the reusable statement in a variable and reuse wherever needed further down in your flow control:

```
var splitted= target.Split(':')[0] + ": ";
if (_Timing != splitted)
   _Timing = splitted;
```

the same goes for the linq queries :

```
var student = db.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Joe");
if (student  != null)
{
  // do something here with student
}
```

if you want to avoid writing the linq query then you can introduce methods too:

```
public Student GetStudentByName(string name)
{
   return db.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Joe");
}
```

and reuse it:

```
var student = GetStudentByName("Joe");
if (student  != null)
{
  // do something here with student
}
```

Comment: is there any to use one line code? for example if the right side condition is true then assigning the output to the left side.

Comment: you don't need to worry about that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement **you say that**:

*I can do this due to answers received:*

```
var splitted= target.Split(':')[0] + ": ";
if (_Timing != splitted)
   _Timing = splitted;
```

*But I don't want to do something like this, because splitted will remain in memory. I'm looking for a way to not saving this temporary data into memory.
Is there any advice?*

Yes There is one way to explicity remove variable from a memory.

You can try this to achieve that same thing and the variable `splitted` no longer remains in memory:

```
var splitted= target.Split(':')[0] + ": ";
if (_Timing != splitted)
{
   _Timing = splitted;
   splitted = null;
   GC.Collect(); // It this stage the 'splitted' is not longer remain in the memory.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `if` block.

```
  _Timing = target.Split(':')[0] + ": ";
```

Move assignment out of the if block

```
var student = db.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Joe");
if (student  != null)
{
  // 
}
```

Comment: removing the "if-block" indeed seems like the more elegant solution, considering OP wants _Timing to always be that.
(just commenting this before the Rule-Nazis come in to say "Code only solutions don't help" and downvote this.)